# How can you select and filter dictionary keys based on their values using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Given a `Dictionary<int, double>`

How can I select the keys that have values less than `localThreshold`?

For example, If I have:

```
var someDict = new Dictionary<int, double>() {
    {1, 392.3},
    {2, 612},
    {3, 981} ... };
```

I'd like to get the value 1 if `localThreshold` was 400 (assuming there were no other dictionary values less than 400).

Comment: please see below answers. they provide a idea to do what i'm expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can ba multiple values that match the condition -

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> dict = new Dictionary<int,decimal>();
dict.Add(1, 392.3m); 
dict.Add(2, 612m); 
dict.Add(3, 981m); 
dict.Add(4, 344.23m);
List<int> Result = dict.Where(x => x.Value < 400).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. :-)

> Example: If the dictionary contain { (1,392.3) , (2, 612),(3,981),(4,344.23)...}

```
private IDictionary<int, decimal> myDict = new Dictionary<int,decimal>
{
    {1, 392.3m},
    {2, 612m},
    {3, 981m},
    {4, 344.23m}
}
```

> now i want to select a key by condition if(dictionary.Value less than localVar) then select the key.

```
public int[] GetKeysWhereValueLessThan(decimal value)
{
    return myDict
        .Where(kv => kv.Value < value)
        .Select(kv => kv.Key)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dictionary<int, double> d = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        //(1,392.3) , (2, 612),(3,981),(4,344.23)
        d.Add(1, 392.3);
        d.Add(2, 612);
        d.Add(3, 987);
        d.Add(4, 344.23);

        //if(dictionary.Value less than localVar)
        double localVar = 500;
        var res = d.Where(i => i.Value < localVar).Select(j => j.Key);

        foreach(var v in res) Console.WriteLine(v);
        //1
        //4
```

**EDIT**: I was not fast enough...